# Could somebody recommend a book about development of portable C/C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, portability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

I am faced with the problem of portable code development (C or C++).
Could somebody advise me which book could help in this question?

***Edited:***

Actually I don't know the types of platforms. I was asked to write a simple program. This program must be portable. I am not expert in this question. I don't understand what it means and what should I do.

***Edited***

Here is an article devoted to this problem:
http://www.feyrer.de/PGC/Fighting_the_Lemmings.pdf
As I understood, the problem is real.
I'd like to research this question before writing my program.

Comment: It would probably be useful to mention specific platforms you need to support.

Comment: What do you mean "C/C++ code"? Suggestion: stay away from multi-language source files!

Comment: Perhaps this is really 2 questions, since C and C++ are quite different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How 'portable' is portable? DO you mean just Windows/Linux or do you mean it must also port to an 8051 uProc?

The C standard library and C++ are pretty much well supported everywhere. Some C++11 features aren't implemented on all compilers - but the common ones are.

The tricky part comes when you want to talk to anything in the OS or hardware - at which  point it might be worth just using something like Qt or WxWidgets - or sticking to Boost.

Comment: Actually I don't know the types of platforms. I was asked to write a simple program. This program must be portable. I am not expert in this question. I don't understand what does it mean and what should I do.

Comment: For simple programs just stick to stuff that is in the standard C (or C++) Programming language book.

Comment: Downvoted because it seems to trivialize how difficult portable code is to create. I definitely support the "how portable is portable" remark but still, portability is *hard*.